# How to hide ribbon or control user action in microsoft word 2010 vb.net

Tags: vb.net, add-in

When user clicks on my programmatically written add-in for Microsoft Word 2010 code does series of actions on the content of document. It takes quite a while for the task to be completed if the document is lets say 40 to 50 pages and the UI was freezing and remained in not responding state till the process completed.

To deal with that problem i used a background worker and added a progress bar so user should know work is under process.

Now while the document is being processed UI does not freeze but user is free to click other customized addins, change content of document etc.

I want to hide the ribbon(including home, insert, Addins) All of it after the user presses any of my addin buttons on the ribbon and show it again when the process completes.

please guide how to achieve this functionality.

Comment: i tried modal technique by doing

Dim myBar As New myProgressBarForm1()
         'myBar.ShowDialog()

in this case form on which progress bar is does gets focus and everything on the back on word is not accessible which i want but the important code is written after 'myBar.ShowDialog() which does not run and so progress bar does not progress as it is supposed to.

Comment: Put these details as part of question

Answer (score 1):

Show the progress dialog after starting Background Worker. Once background worker is invoked, and the dialog is shown as Modal, it will freeze the Doc.